# Failing core web vitals despite 90%+ PSI results

Tags: core-web-vitals

Site : [www.purelocal.com.au](http://www.purelocal.com.au)

Tested 1000's of URL's in Google PSI - all are Green 90%+.
However , in Google webmaster tools = 0 GOOD URLS.
Can someone please explain what Google requires and what we can do to pass core web vitals before JUNE ?
We've spent months optimising everything and cannot further optimise but Google says that NONE of our URL's pass core web vitals...it's just ridiculous.

Comment: When you say "Green 90%+" are you referring to the lab-based Lighthouse score? That score is not actually related to the real-user field data used by tools like Search Console. The "field data" section of PSI is what matters most for Core Web Vitals performance.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your website's report in the [CrUX Dashboard](https://datastudio.google.com/c/u/0/reporting/bbc5698d-57bb-4969-9e07-68810b9fa348/page/keDQB?params=%7B%22origin%22:%22https:%2F%2Fwww.purelocal.com.au%22%7D), there are a couple of things you could optimize more:

[image]

First, your site's LCP is right on the edge of having 75% good desktop experiences, and phone experiences are below that at 66% good. https://web.dev/optimize-lcp/ has some great tips for addressing LCP issues.

Second, while your site's desktop FID experiences are overwhelmingly good (98%), you do seem to have a significant issue for phone users (only 44% good). There are similarly great tips in the https://web.dev/optimize-fid/ article.

[image]

While the big green "98" score on PSI makes it look like the page is nearly perfect, what matters most in terms of the user experience is real field data. That information can be found in the "Field Data" and "Origin Summary" sections of the report.

---

You mentioned in the comments that your server response time is an issue. I can confirm this with lab testing:

[image]

https://webpagetest.org/graph_page_data.php?tests=210506_AiDcJ0_0283e8c51814788904bdf19cebe7a5c8&medianMetric=TTFB&fv=1&median_run=1&zero_start=true&control=NOSTAT#TTFB

[image]

https://webpagetest.org/result/210506_AiDcJ0_0283e8c51814788904bdf19cebe7a5c8/8/details/#waterfall_view_step1

The long light blue bar on line 1 of the chart above shows how long it takes your server to respond to the request. In this case the time to first byte (TTFB) is 1.132 seconds. This is going to be a huge problem for most users to achieve a fast LCP because in these tests it takes 1.9 seconds just to get the HTML to the client. No amount of frontend optimizations can make the HTML arrive sooner than that. You need to focus on backend optimizations to get the TTFB down.

I can't give you any specific hosting recommendations but it does seem like the shared hosting is adversely affecting your users' LCP performance.

Comment: I cannot find anymore ways to speed up the webite aside from removing crucial features , eg : Google places , Javascript , top logo etc. I use a shared server because the platform I use forces me to and this has a long server response (1 second approx)...getting a dedicated server with them cost $400usd/month which is beyond my budget at present...  I know the metrics are obviously not good enough but I simply cannot optimise anything further , to my knowledge , I can hard-cache URLs but users update content regularly so thats not an option.. I'd like coding examples of how I can fix this.

Comment: every single in MOBILE is failing core web vitals , i'm aware of the results but I have no practical way of fixing the code , everything has been optimised but now at a brickwall...my server does not respond to increase the server response time so yes ,this is very frustrating.

Comment: Added more to my answer to address your point about shared hosting and long server response times.

Comment: The URL : https://www.purelocal.com.au/milk-crate-studios  in google psi has time to interactive of about 4 seconds , I have one big merged JS at the top , async or deferring this does nothing...the merged javascript is a big pile of multiple functions -- no idea how to optimise -- can anyone help.

Comment: would anyone know how to optimise the merged JS file : https://ik.imagekit.io/mqpttb8ig/merger_ege2QxuqD.js

Comment: I've tried contacting IBM softlayer to fix the server response but they say it's held with a 3rd party and I cannot control the server...

Comment: www.purelocal.com.au - does anyone know where this domain is hosted so we can contact the server and ask why the server is so slow?